# How to show all types of documents (.docx, .csv, .xls, .pdf, .txt) stored in s3 in android application?

Tags: android, amazon-s3, kotlin

I have multiple type of file stored in s3 e.g; .docx, .txt, .csv, .xls, etc. I want to display all these documents in my android application. Is there any common way to display all types of documents in android? (Like in iOS we can use WKWebView to display all type of files)

I have tried WebView. Its only displaying .docx, .txt and .pdf files. But I want to display .xls and .csv too.

Comment: `WebView` itself won't display docx or PDF files even. There is no common way to easily display all those files. You can use search to find libraries that display each of them.

Comment: Yeah I have used "http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" to display documents in WebView

Comment: that's google docs who converted your document to HTML page, not the WebView

Comment: The libraries take way too much space on android for each type of document. It will increase the app size.

Comment: use intent and let the user choose the desired application to open a particular file type

Comment: for sure it will, but you can't use magic out of Hogwarts: Either you use libraries to open documents, which will increase APK size, or you don't use them, APK size is small, but you are not able to open documents...

Comment: @AkshayKatariya If I want to use intent to display files, I will need to have the files in android storage, right? I need to show the files content directly from s3 link.

Answer (score 0):

I know this may not be the best solution but, I would recommend you to download the file temporarily and open it via intent because it is not possible that you can open all type of file in `webview`.

You can write a utility class to download the file and then pass it to intent and **delete after the task is done**.

```
private open inner class DownloadFile : AsyncTask<String, Void, String>() {

        override fun onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute()
            AppUtil.showDialog(context)
        }

        override fun doInBackground(vararg strings: String): String? {

            var fName = strings[0].substring(strings[0].lastIndexOf('/') + 1)
            fName = fName.replace(" ", "_")


            val fileUrl = strings[0]
            val extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
            val folder = File(extStorageDirectory, "My_Application_name")
            folder.mkdir()

            val mFile = File(folder, fName)

            try {
                mFile.createNewFile()
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }

            FileDownloader.downloadFile(fileUrl, mFile)
            return fName
        }

        override fun onPostExecute(result: String?) {
            super.onPostExecute(result)
            AppUtil.dismissDialog()
            openMyFile(result)
        }
    }
```

Then use following intent to open that file

```
fun openFile(url: File) {

    val uri = Uri.fromFile(url)

    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
    if (url.toString().contains(".doc") || url.toString().contains(".docx")) {
        // Word document
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/msword")
    } else if (url.toString().contains(".pdf")) {
        // PDF file
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf")
    } else if (url.toString().contains(".ppt") || url.toString().contains(".pptx")) {
        // Powerpoint file
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint")
    } else if (url.toString().contains(".xls") || url.toString().contains(".xlsx")) {
        // Excel file
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.ms-excel")
    } else if (url.toString().contains(".zip") || url.toString().contains(".rar")) {
        // WAV audio file
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/x-wav")
    } else if (url.toString().contains(".rtf")) {
        // RTF file
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/rtf")
    } else if (url.toString().contains(".wav") || url.toString().contains(".mp3")) {
        // WAV audio file
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "audio/x-wav")
    } else if (url.toString().contains(".gif")) {
        // GIF file
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/gif")
    } else if (url.toString().contains(".jpg") || url.toString().contains(".jpeg") || url.toString().contains(".png")) {
        // JPG file
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/jpeg")
    } else if (url.toString().contains(".txt")) {
        // Text file
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "text/plain")
    } else if (url.toString().contains(".3gp") || url.toString().contains(".mpg") || url.toString().contains(".mpeg") || url.toString().contains(
            ".mpe"
        ) || url.toString().contains(".mp4") || url.toString().contains(".avi")
    ) {
        // Video files
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "video/*")
    } else {
        //if you want you can also define the intent type for any other file
        //additionally use else clause below, to manage other unknown extensions
        //in this case, Android will show all applications installed on the device
        //so you can choose which application to use
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*")
    }

    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
    startActivity(intent)

}
```

Once your task is over you can delete the downloaded file.